# initializing first character with zero and not other?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I found below shown piece of code on libcurl website, but I don't get the reason of setting first char to 0 `errbuf[0] = 0;` ? What about the others?

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;

  char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");

  /* provide a buffer to store errors in */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);

  /* set the error buffer as empty before performing a request */
  errbuf[0] = 0;

  /* perform the request */
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  /* if the request did not complete correctly, show the error
  information. if no detailed error information was written to errbuf
  show the more generic information from curl_easy_strerror instead.
  */
  if(res != CURLE_OK) {
    size_t len = strlen(errbuf);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", res);
    if(len)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", errbuf,
              ((errbuf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
    else
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
  }
}
```

Comment: `errorbuf[0] = 0;` makes errorbuf what you would call "an empty string".  It's a null-terminated string and it now begins with a null.  curl will not read past this 0, so it does not matter what the other characters contain.

Comment: Setting only the first char to 0 is an optimization (only sets terminating 0 of a string), no need to initialize the rest of the buffer. (which could have been done using : `char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE]{};`)

Comment: @DrewDormann if not a duplicate at least an explanation.

Comment: All of the standard and most of the non-standard, character array-eating string handling functions expect the last character of relevance in the string to be followed by a null character, a 0, so that the function knows when to stop reading. There is no need to null any characters after the null because the reader has stopped reading and won't ever see them.

Comment: The code is using `CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER` to have `curl_easy_perform()` write errors into `errbuf`. `errbuf[0] = 0;` is being used to initialize `errbuf` to an "empty" C-style string first so that `strlen(errbuf)` is always meaningful, even if no error is written to it. But, do note that since 7.60, libcurl will do that initialization for you, making this line of code redundant.